# Trusted Site in IE - html title is ignored

Tags: html, internet-explorer, sites, trusted

When we add our domain as a trusted site to IE, then the html 'title' tag is ignored and the page url is shown in the browser header bar.

Whn we remove our domain from the trusted sites list then the correct title is shown in the header bar.

This only occurs in a popup window.

Why is this?!

( I should add, this is in IE8 - same thing occurs in any mode)

Comment: I don't know, but this sounds like a security measure. If it is, it is unlikely to be possible to turn off

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to marktucks for pointing me in the right direction.

In my case the solution was to 'enable' the 'Allow script-initiated windows without size or position constraints' option in IE security settings for the Trusted Sites Zone.  The title, rather than the page URL is then displayed in javascript initiated pop-ups.

Comment: Thanks for for noting your solution here.  If this is the best answer, it's OK to accept your own answer.  You can also upvote marktucks' answer if it was useful.

Comment: Thanks for the tip - have accepted my own answer as this solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

I think this may be due to this security advisory where spoofing of the title bar was possible in popups http://secunia.com/advisories/14335/