# window.title not updating on ie9

Tags: popup, internet-explorer-9, title

I´m setting the title of a popup window on ie9, but it´s not getting updated.

Strange thing is that inspecting the elements, the title is correctly setted, but the browser displays the url regardless.

Also, if I open the window like this:

window.open(url,"_blank") then it works

However:

window.open(url,"_blank",'height=200, width=400')  (i.e with any specs setted) triggers that strange behaviour

Anyone has any clues on it? any workaround appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It only happens if the site is marked as trusted, and this solves it:

[Trusted Site in IE - html title is ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5116893/trusted-site-in-ie-html-title-is-ignored)